# Zend Framework - Form Element - setValue() Not Working?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to set the value of a submit button, from the default one (the name of the element) that Zend_Form assigns it.

Does anyone know the reason this isn't working:

```
    $button = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('login_button');
    $button->setValue('Login');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change label of submit button use this:

```
$button = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('login_button');
$button->setLabel('Login');
```

Comment: Thanks! I had managed to 'fudge' it by passing the label of the button through in the Zend_Form_Element_Submit() construct but didn't want to work this way as it goes against my coding standard/style...